# Is watching people kiss on the lips haram

Tags: halal-haram

I was watching a movie alone when there was a kissing scene and instead of looking away I watched it. But other than my parents no one has said watching kissing is haram. So my question is, is watching kissing (kissing on lips) haram?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is Haram!
Any act has a bad scence which they call those days "+18" you can't watch it, Allah says in Quran:
قُل لِّلْمُؤْمِنِينَ يَغُضُّوا مِنْ أَبْصَارِهِمْ وَيَحْفَظُوا فُرُوجَهُمْ ۚ ذَٰلِكَ أَزْكَىٰ لَهُمْ ۗ إِنَّ اللَّهَ خَبِيرٌ بِمَا يَصْنَعُونَ (30)

(30) Tell the believing men to reduce [some] of their vision and guard their private parts. That is purer for them. Indeed, Allah is Acquainted with what they do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is haram and not permissible at all. We as believers need to lower our gaze as Allah (swt) and his Messenger instructed us to and never see bad things. If we can’t control our eyes, we have a really big problem. We never ever should see bad things with our eyes because it’s always haram. We must control our eyes otherwise 4 bad things will happen,

1. No inner peace
2. Distress
3. Losing faith in Allah (swt)
4. Becoming a Great/Huge sinner

We should NEVER EVER see bad things with our eyes

For more information you can see the Quran, Surah,
Al-Nur: 30-31
Al-Hijr: 75
Al-Dhar: 11-12

Answer (score -1):

Actually the fact is not watching kissing scene... seeing a movie contains kissing scene is not good. But  we see the movies for just its constructive content or creative story and have to do gymnastics in midth of the movie during a intimate scene...

I assume such movies character dress are not modest in most of the cases. So it is better for Muslims to refrain him from these movies.